# What's the best way to scrape keywords from Twitter?

Tags: automation, twitter, scrape

I have an idea for a script that I would like to use for a contest on Twitter. The script I want to build will scrape keywords from a tweet (someone I'm following) and then automate an action when they're found.

My question is, what would be the best way to build this script? Should I script the webpage or an API to get faster results? I need the script to be reliable and very fast because I'll be using this for a contest. Ideally I would like the script to obtain the keywords a few seconds before the tweets are posted online (if possible) to have a better chance on winning.

Thoughts and suggestions? Btw I'm not a developer but I am planning to hire someone to build this script for me after I get the necessary information.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to scrape the webpage.  Use the API.  They have a REST API or you could use something like [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org).  I suggest having a look at their website, see the examples and see if it fits in with what you would like to do.

In my experience the tweets will show up in the API before the are updated on the website.